# Arguments not working properly in SASS @mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've been using sass (specifically the scss bit) with my spreadsheets, and until now it had been going well.  I use quite a few CSS3 features that aren't fully implemented yet in all browsers, and I figured that I could just write a mixin that did something to this extent:

```
@mixin multilang($what, $value) {
    $what: $value;
    -khtml-#{$what}: $value;
    -webkit-#{$what}: $value;
    -o-#{$what}: $value;
    -moz-#{$what}: $value;
}
```

And call it like `@include multilang(user-select, none);`, but instead, my compiled CSS is littered with things like `-khtml-none: none`, etc.

Now, I figure I'm just doing something wrong here, but I can't quite seem to figure out what it is.  I tried putting quotes around things, using named arguments, etc., but everything basically has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap your first $what like this

```
@mixin multilang($what, $value) {
  #{$what}: $value;
  -khtml-#{$what}: $value;
  -webkit-#{$what}: $value;
  -o-#{$what}: $value;
  -moz-#{$what}: $value;
}
```

Comment: This did it.  OH! I just realized why, I guess.  I was assigning `$what` to the value of `$value` before, since `$foo:$bar;` assigns `$bar` to `$foo`. =/  Thanks!